# Sort multidimensional array with two arrays inside?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I would like to sort my array according to a value which is represented by another array. So, this right here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13.31421
            [1] => WP_Post Object (...)
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.213
            [1] => WP_Post Object (...)
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 144.314
            [1] => WP_Post Object (...)
        )
)
```

I would like to sort my array by number on index `0` which you can see e.g. at the index: `[0][0]` = `13.31421`.

I already tried to find some answers on google but the solutions didn't really work out:

```
uasort($post_distance, function($a, $b) {
    return $a[0] - $b[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the usort function.

```php
usort ( array &$array , callable $value_compare_func ) : bool
```

add this method to your code

```php
function compare($a, $b)
{
    if ( $a[0] == $b[0] ) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ( $a[0] < $b[0] ) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

then simply call the usort function

```php
usort($post_distance,"compare");
```

Comment: Add a note about the use the spaceship operator to make it  `return $a <=> $b` for PHP 7 and above.